# Anyway to remove white screen after splash screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

When on a slow connection, my Ionic app shows a white screen briefly on a slow connection. I am not importing any providers and the page does not have cordova plugins so it should not be an issue.

Is there any way to 100% remove this. What I was thinking, is to add an output to the pages the app can load on. When and event is emitted on ionViewDidEnter(), I hide the splash screen. This should hide the splash screen when the page is rendered.

Note that I have uncommented the service worker code in index.html and building as prod to create the necessary files.

What do you think?

**EDIT**: add config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.ionic" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>ionic</name>
    <description>Ionic</description>
    <author email="ionic@gmail.com" href="http://www.ionic.com/">Ionic</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="0xFFFFFFFF" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-deeplinks" spec="^1.0.15">
        <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="ionic" />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="ionic.com" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_HOST" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_3_HOST" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_4_HOST" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_5_HOST" value=" " />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="^1.8.3" />
    <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" spec="^4.1.0">
        <variable name="LOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app requires access to your location for navigation purposes" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="^0.8.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.3.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.4" />
    <engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
</widget>
```

**[Solution]** - Seems removing the splashscreen.hide() fixes the issue.

Comment: Add your config.xml file detail here.

Comment: Added a copy with some placeholder (such as email, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrease value of Fade Screen duration

```
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
```

and do below steps.

- Remove platform : `ionic cordova platform rm <android|ios>`
- Add platform : `ionic cordova platform add >android|ios>`
- Run your app : `ionic run <android|ios> --prod --device`

Hope this will remove your white screen issue after splash.

Comment: Didn’t work. The white screen now shows on even fast connections. I think I will use your solution, together with the ionviewdidenter

Comment: I changed the `FadeSplashScreenDuration` but all I had to do was comment `this.splashScreen.hide();`